# Android Udacity tutorial - adding data to that listview

Tags: android, list

I'm doing the Android Udacity tutorial on learning how to make an android app.

The video tutorial tells me to use some sort of view with a fragment - but then the text acknowledges that this doesn't exist anymore as a starting option, and instead of editing the tutorial they just ask I read up about fragments.

So I did, and fragments are confusing? There seem to be two imports I can user for fragments - android.app and android.support.v4.app? Which am I meant to use (not for making the same code as the tutorial, but for making quality code today)?

And then, for this exercise - just a view with a list - would I even use a fragment or would I kick it off with an activity directly?

I guess I'm asking what is best practice for my MainActivity class to make a screen that has a (i know it won't scroll bc there are so few items!) scrollable list with the entries

```
bob
jane
marko
helena
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use fragments for a simple list like this. 
Here's a simple solution for static content:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
String[] names = new String[] {"bob","jane","marko","helena"};
//Param 1 is the context, 2 is the layout, 3 is the textview that's changing to match the name
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: that's really really neat, thanks. Can you add in how i'd "fragment" it too, just to sate my curiosity?

Comment: You mean how you would do it if the listView were inside of a fragment:Or if the fra

Comment: ummmm... i dunno, let's say the listView was inside of a fragment? (i don't really understand the distinction you're making)

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, not entirely sure what difference fragment makes.
But if the list was inside a fragment you would just call
getView() before findViewById (So it searches the view inside the fragment for the list):
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);